# qooxdoo selectbox in popup

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

i'm having some issues with the qx.ui.popup.Popup. Because it is added to the root and and is not a child of any widget.
For example: If you add a selectBox on a normal popup, because the selectBox is built from a list on a new popup, the original popup will close.

I am using many more popups on my tables/forms. And if i include these tables/forms in other popups/menus, i have the same issues.

Is there a way of me telling the popup it is a part of a widget, so that Widget.contains(..) will not fail the check. I still need the to act like popups, meaning they will still probably need to be added on root?

Regards,
Mark

Edit:

What you think if i extend the Popup and add a "virtualLayoutParent" property to it.
Then i "override" the __onPointerDown function in the qx.ui.popup.Manager to check the Widget.container(virtualLayoutParent)?

Answer (score 0):

The auto hiding behavior of qx.ui.popup.Popup is configurable by the property `autoHide`which you maybe want to experiment with: http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.popup.Popup~setAutoHide

But you could also decide to not use popups generally, but use qx.ui.window.Window for some of your widgets, which allows more control on visibility and modality.

Comment: Yes i thought of using the autoHide for this, but i would need to listen to all the lower children when they close/disappear, if i wanted to toggle the autoHide. But i'm trying to build the thing as modular as a i can, so i don't think it's a good way to go. Windows would also cause the same issues..--- For the moment i created my own property, vitualParentLayout and overrided the Widget.contains, to also check for those